# Infura returns strange error: `query returned more than 10000 results`

Tags: web3js, infura

The purpose of the function below is to track USDT that is transferred to and from Yearn and Fulcrum.

When I call search_liquidity(_toBlock), I get an error that says `Returned error: query returned more than 10000 results`. This error is confusing to me because I even get this error when I query USDT transactions between Yearn and Fulcrum from a single block.

Are there situations where Infura returns this error even though the query did not return more than 10000 results? Is this a problem with the Fulcrum address I selected?

```
let search_liquidity = async(_toBlock) => {
        try {
            withdraw_events = await USDT_contract_interface.getPastEvents('Transfer', 
                {
                    filter: {
                        src: '0xE6354ed5bC4b393a5Aad09f21c46E101e692d447', // Yearn sender and receiver address for USDT
                        dst: '0xf013406a0b1d544238083df0b93ad0d2cbe0f65f' // what I suspect to be the sender and receiver address for USDT for Fulcrum
                    }, 
                    fromBlock: yearn_liquidity_transfer_addresses.starter_block, 
                    toBlock: _toBlock 
                }
            )

            deposit_events = await USDT_contract_interface.getPastEvents('Transfer', 
                {
                    filter: {
                        src: '0xf013406a0b1d544238083df0b93ad0d2cbe0f65f', 
                        dst: '0xE6354ed5bC4b393a5Aad09f21c46E101e692d447'
                    }, 
                    fromBlock: yearn_liquidity_transfer_addresses.starter_block, 
                    toBlock: _toBlock 
                }
            )

            events.push(...withdraw_events,...deposit_events)
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post `USDT_contract_interface` if you want anyone here to be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Same goes for `yearn_liquidity_transfer_addresses.starter_block`.

Comment: And for whatever value of `_toBlock` you pass when you call `search_liquidity`.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out what was wrong with the code. I will keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the indexed event parameters for the Transfer Event for USDT is actually `from` and `to` instead of `src` and `dst`. When I switched to the correct parameters, I started receiving a normal quantity of events. When I failed to use the filters correctly, it just sent me every Transfer event in the contract.

I thought that all ERC20 tokens would have the same indexed parameters for this, but this is not the case. DAI uses `src` and `dst`.

Answer (score 1):

The "Returned error: query returned more than 10000 results" error is a general limitation of infura.io. In the case you get more than 10000 events with your request, this message will be returned and you get no result.

But, there is a solution. Implement a kind of fork and join for your query. In the case you get the message split the from block and to block parameter until the intervals are small enough. Then merge all results. This works well and the performance is ok.

Simplified code:

```
readEventsRange(start: number, end: number) {

   this.runningJobs += 1;
   this.contractInstance.getPastEvents('allEvents', {fromBlock: start, toBlock: end}, 
        (errors: Error, events: any) => {
        if (!errors) {
            if (events.length > 0) {
               
                // process events here
                
                this.runningJobs -= 1;
            } else {
                this.runningJobs -= 1;
                if (errors.message === 'Returned error: query returned more than 10000 results') {
                    const middle = Math.round((start + end) / 2);
                    console.log('Infura 10000 limit [' + start + '..' + end + '] ' +
                    '->  [' + start + '..' + middle + '] ' + 
                    'and [' + (middle + 1) + '..' + end + ']');
                    this.readEventsRange(start, middle);
                    this.readEventsRange(middle + 1, end);
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I've implemented this [here](https://github.com/MarkusSprunck/ethereum-event-scan/blob/master/src/app/services/reader.service.ts).